# iwlwifi on ubuntu 18.10 dns resolve issue 9560

Tags: networking, dns, 18.10, iwlwifi

I've been having issues with a clean install of Ubuntu 18.10 on multiple laptops with iwlwifi chips in particular the 9560 2.4/5ghz chip, the DNS would randomly stop resolving or be extremely slow to resolve, I also experienced intermittently while browsing an error page about a protocol error when using the iwlwifi inbuilt module.

I find the contents of resolv.conf pointing to nameserver 127.0.0.53 to be part of the issue, changing this back to my local nameserver or googles fixes the issue temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

after a fair bit of googling and just taking a few stabs in the dark I've come up with the following that seems to fix it.

1:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

in the [main] section add:
  "DNS=DHCP"
then save and close

2:

```
$ sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
```

3:

```
$ sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

4:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```